# MS Word page layout adjustment with powershell

Tags: powershell, layout, printing, ms-word

Any idea how to change the print page layout in MS Word with PowerShell? 
Let's say for example I want to setup the document to print with Letterhead and plain paper or simply switch the duplex printing (one side or both sides) (pardon the french display ;-)) : 
[image]

I know how to create the document and all but not how to adjust these printing preferences.

Basically I need to know how to set these properties, the final script would be something like :

```
$Word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
$Document = $Word.Documents.Add()
$Selection = $Word.Selection
$Selection.TypeText("Testing")

#SET PRINT LAYOUT OPTIONS HERE, WHICH I DON'T KNOW HOW :)

$File = 'C:\temp\test.docx'
$Document.SaveAs([ref]$File,[ref]$SaveFormat::wdFormatDocument)
$word.Quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't test it yet, but had the same question and hopefully now the answer:

With `$PrinterSettings = new-object System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings` you can see most of the (default) printer settings. `$PrinterSettings.CanDuplex` to check if your printer supports Duplex.

```bsh
$DefaultPrinter = Get-WmiObject -Query " SELECT * FROM Win32_Printer WHERE Default=$true" | Select -Expand Name
Set-PrintConfiguration $DefaultPrinter -DuplexingMode TwoSidedLongEdge -PaperSize Letterhead
```

That should do the Job.
You can also do:

```bsh
$PrinterSettings = Get-PrintConfiguration -PrinterName "Microsoft XPS Document Writer"
$PrinterSettings.DuplexingMode = "TwoSidedLongEdge"
$PrinterSettings.PaperSize = "Letterhead"
```

For more info about the options: [Set-PrintConfiguration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/printmanagement/set-printconfiguration?view=win10-ps)

DuplexingMode options:

OneSided
TwoSidedLongEdge
TwoSidedShortEdge

Comment: This is pretty useful ! However it doesn't adjust the settings in Word like I need to but directly in the printer driver configuration instead. I'll still check it out thanks !

Comment: It cant be done with Word as far as i know. If you find it, please post it. Only thing that can is select the active printer ($Word.activeprinter = "printer name"). And i think it is also setting (changing) the default printer, but maybe because win10 has the function to auto select the default printer (last printer used at that location), haven't test it with that function off.

Comment: If you don't want to change it that way maybe you can add the same printer with other config (call it printername_duplex or something) so you only have to set the active printer in word.

Comment: Actually I remembered I found out to adjust print settings in Word a while ago I helped a guy on Reddit : check my comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/c3ajcl/printer_word_doc_to_specific_printer_help/erpv9s4?utm_medium=android_app&utm_source=share I'm on mobile so I don't have time to post an answer here on stack, if you can that would be appreciated. It's all about the .printout method. Not sure you can adjust all though, will have to check back when I'm back at work next week.